# CSS media query for differentiate ipad Air 2019 from iPad Pro2020

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I'm looking for a css mediaquery that is able to differentiate the ipadAir 2019 from the ipadPro2020, I tried to use pixels or dpi, but nothing works.
Do you have any suggestion? Do I need to rely on Javascript?

Comment: Hi. Is your question for a personal use? The rason for my question is that it is not good practice to use harware dependant media queries. Better not use "....-device-width" or "...-device-pixel-ratio" in a media query.

Comment: Ipad Pro 2020 has `1668 x 2388` resolution and IPad Air 2019 - `1920 x 1080` as per google search. So you can try something like `@media (min-width: 1668px) and (min-height: 2388px) {}` to target the Pro version

Comment: I will give a try! Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You can stack the media queries. First, style the IPad Air 2019, after that, change the styling for the  Ipad Pro 2020. It will look like this `@media (min-width: 1900px) { /* IPad Air 2019, 1920 x 1080 */ } @media (min-width: 2000px) { /* change things for Ipad Pro 2020, 2732x2048 */ }`

Comment: Unfortunately the media queries don't work, apparently the page is rendered in Kiosk Mode